# How do I provide parameters for the component when working with imperative Dialogs?

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

when working with imperative dialogs, as shown on the demo page:

```
let pDialog = this.dialogService.showCustomDialog({
  component: LoginDialogComponent,
  providers: [{provide: TEST_VALUE, useValue: 'Just an example'}],
  isModal: true,
  styles: {'width': '350px'},
  clickOutsideToClose: true,
  enterTransitionDuration: 400,
  leaveTransitionDuration: 400
});
```

How do I provide arguments for the LoginDialogComponent, should it need some? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance,
c

Comment: Ok, so what I did was augmenting the config of "showCustomDialog" and then accessing it using the MdlDialogReference of the component. I guess this is the way to go?

Comment: I had a sneak peek to the code of this library but it seems to me that `MdlDialogReference` holds no reference to the `LoginDialogComponent` instance to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example there is already some code for this use-case.

`providers: [{provide: TEST_VALUE, useValue: 'Just an example'}],`

You can use this to inject the string `Just an example` into the construtor of `LoginDialogComponent`.

Before you have to initialize `TEST_VALUE` the following way:

```
const TEST_VALUE = new OpaqueToken("test_value");
```

Then you can extend your components constructor this way to get the value:

```
constructor(@Inject(TEST_VALUE) private myValue: string) {}
```

**Or**

Instead of a string you can also pass an object. This would look this way:

```
providers: [{provide: TEST_VALUE, useValue: <IMyDialogArgs>{
    foo: "foo",
    bar: 0
}}],
```

Comment: Hello philipooo, 
thanks for you answer. So if I wanted to pass several strings, I will need multiple opaque tokens?

Comment: You can pass whatever you want. Instead of a string you could also pass an object with different keys. I added a example above.